# How do I prove that $(ABC)^{-1} = C^{-1} B^{-1} A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Please help me answering this problem! thank you :)

> Prove that for any nonsingular matrices $A$, $B$, and $C$, the equation
>   $$(ABC)^{-1} = C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$$
>   holds. (Hint: Assume $D$ is the inverse of $ABC$, thus $DABC =I$. Post-multiply both sides of the matrix equation by $C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$ and proceed from there.)

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjKpB.png)

Comment: You're expected to show the effort that you've made in attempting to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: Well, what do you get when you try to multiply (abc) by $a^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}$?  [Actually, I don't think this is true.  I think (abc)^1 = c^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1]$. ]

Comment: $$(ABC)^{-1}=[A(BC)]^{-1}=(BC)^{-1}A^{-1}=C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}.$$

Comment: If you want to share a math-problem you need to explain what you're arguments are. What are A, B and C? The statement as it is given there is not even true for every choice of A, B and C.

Comment: You title is wrong.

Comment: Better to start with $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}\times A^{-1}$. Then by recursion, you can prove your statement.

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz You're assuming that such a fact is assumed?

Comment: @barakmanos is it wrong to assume that OP had no idea? why should this be off-topic? OP said initially 'please help me answering this problem!' I don't see how that's any different from asking for a hint

Comment: @BCLC: Where exactly did I say it was off-topic? I told OP that he or she was expected to show the effort that they've made in attempting to solve the problem on their own.

Comment: @barakmanos Sorry! I meant to make that two commenta

Answer (score 7):

$$(ABC)C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}=AB\underbrace{(CC^{-1})}_{=I}B^{-1}A^{-1}=ABB^{-1}A^{-1}=AA^{-1}=I$$
Therefore, the inverse of $ABC$ is $C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$. I let you make all the necessary justification (like associativity of matriciel product...)

Comment: You showed that it is true, but: Without knowing the result, how one can show that result in terms of A,B,C is that one?

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz, You should know the group theoric property, if  $(G,\circ)$ be a group, the $\forall A,B\in G$, $$(A\circ B)^{-1}=B^{-1}\circ A^{-1}.$$ And then try to apply your intuition and then show that your imagination is correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. let A,B,C be matrices and $ C=AB $
2. $ B=A^{-1}AB = A^{-1}C $
3. $ A=ABB^{-1} = CB^{-1} $, then by using $C=AB$ we have
4. $C=AB =[CB^{-1}][A^{-1}C] $
5. $C=AB =[CB^{-1}A^{-1}]C $ where 
   $[CB^{-1}A^{-1}] = I$

Therefore:

$B^{-1}A^{-1} = C^{-1}$

By using this result you can extend it to n matrices.

For instance, for you question let $ABC = F$ and $BC = D$. Then you will have $F^{-1} = D^{-1}A^{-1}$ where $D^{-1} = C^{-1}B^{-1} $. Substituting back $D^{-1}$ gives $F^{-1} = C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$.